# SQL Server : Union returns fewer rows (select distinct)

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I'm trying to create a local temp table in SQL Server that includes all account numbers from a set of tables. In the select statement I'm using `DISTINCT`. `Table_1` has `~130k` rows and `Table_2` has `~50k` rows.

But the UNION returns less than `~130k` rows. I know `UNION` returns distinct values but I used `DISTINCT` in the select statement so I don't understand the discrepancy.

```
SELECT X.acct_num
INTO #cat
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(t1.Account_Number AS NVARCHAR(15)) AS acct_num
    FROM table_1 t1

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(t2.AcctNo AS NVARCHAR(15)) AS acct_num
    FROM table_2 t2
) X;
```

This returns ~100k rows.

Comment: UNION also removes duplicates between the tables,

Comment: there are account_numbers common between the tables. and `union` returns only the distinct values from the 2 tables combined.

Comment: What about UNION ALL?

Comment: If still wants record use `UNION ALL`

Comment: To be clear, you're saying `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM table_1` returns 130K rows, but that the final result has fewer than 130K rows?

Comment: if `SELECT DISTINCT Account_Number FROM table_1` returns 130k rows, then that means you are truncating the `Account_Number` when you cast it to  `NVARCHAR(15)`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but either I'm not explaining properly or I just don't follow you. If table_1 shows 130k distinct rows, even if all 50k distinct records in table_2 are common between table_1 and table_2 there would still be at least 130k distinct values

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes that is correct

Comment: I can't think of a single way that could happen. Are you using the exact query `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(t1.Account_Number AS NVARCHAR(15)) AS acct_num FROM table_1 t1` to count the rows too?